# Convergence of logarithmic series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(\log(n+i)-\log n)^2}{n+i}.$$

Does lim $S_{n}$ exist?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^2}{n+k}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^2}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\frac{1}{n}\\ 
=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(\ln(1+x))^2}{1+x}dx=\left[\frac{1}{3}(\ln(1+x))^3\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{3}(\ln(2))^3
$$